# How to execute the code 1st and then introduce delay

Tags: javascript, refactoring, delay, setinterval, intervals

Is there a better way to execute code 1st and then introduced the delay. Right now code is working perfectly. But I want to know is there any better way to write code means without using delayFlag.

Details:

requestConfigs: contains n number of the object which contain details needed to make a fetch request

delayFlag: it will activate after 1st for loop is on the last round

this.getMyData(details): is a function which is fetching data from the endpoint

this.getFetchDetails(): This funtion contains this for loop I try to make the recurtion.

```
for(let i=0 ; i < requestConfigs.length ; i++){

      if(this.state.delayFlag === true){ // NOTE: This approch is the Issue
        await this.delay(5000)
      }

      console.log("5 SEC")
      await this.getMyData(requestConfigs[i])
      await this.setState({ dashboard: dashboardResponse.data, initialDataFeatchFlage: false });

      if(i === requestConfigs.length-1){
        await this.setState({ delayFlag: true });
        this.getFetchDetails();
      }
    }
```

Comment: if your code works, but you want to refactor it or do it in a possible better way, I think you can find a better answer here: https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/

Comment: couldn't able to find an answer in the provided link.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I wasn't clear, but it's not to find an answer, but to ask your question there, to then receive an answer

Comment: Ohh ok Thank you,